# The input value from numeric updown control gets empty after first scroll up while on the screen it's 1

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Inside the form I have input of the type "number" which is rendered as numeric up down control in the form. I have a function that is triggered over mousewheel and keyup events and gets the value of the input. The problem is that when I first scroll the wheel up the value becomes `empty ""` even though on the screen it's displayed as `1`. The actual value becomes 1 after second scroll and the number displayed on the screen gets 2. So what's the reason that numeric updown value gets empty with the first scroll while the number on the screen is actually 1 ? How to solve this inconsistence?

```
    <!--language: lang-js-->
    $(document).on("keyup wheel", "#input3", function () {
    var value = $(this).val()
  });
```

here is the related div

```
<!--language: lang-html-->
               <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                    @Html.EditorFor(b => b.Stock, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-value", id = "input3", min = "0" } })
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <div class="error">
                        <small class="error_form" id="stock_error_message"></small>
                        <div class="icon"></div>
                    </div>
                    <label for="input3">@Html.DisplayNameFor(b => b.Stock)</label>
                </div>
```

Comment: On screen _where_ exacly ?

Comment: @reg on the corresponding form field of course..

Comment: Show full code including your form and field.